# Any alternatives for e.printStackTrace(); in android app development?

Tags: android

guys what are the best alternatives for Error Handling in android.
All in all I dont want my application to shutdown in first attempt.
Say it started, made a http request, error and closed.
I am looking for a warning type error and let it continue further functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: When an error is thrown, you should fix it if it's programming error. For other errors like internet is not accessible when making http request, you should catch it and prompt the user. This has nothing to do with e.printStackTrace(), it simply print the error stack trace to logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when trying to print a stack trace you should always use this:

```
try {
  // DO STUFF
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Log.e(String, String);`

Should work for you

Comment: thanks for quick response but My app still gets forced out.I have tried Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTrace(e); I am working http request with JSONParser

Comment: Well, the app getting force closed is due to the uncaught exceptions in your code. Try using `try-catch` block. And catch for `Exception` rather than any particular one so that every exception will be caught and the app wont force close. But this is not the best programming technique I must warn you.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
 //Code
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```